# checking a tic tac toe game

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x

I'm working on this project where I check a finished tic tac toe game. The user inputs a combination of x's and o's and periods (max of 3) in each row (there are 3 rows). I have to check if either x or o took too many turns. This is what I have:

```
if ttt.count(x) > 5:
                    print("x took too many turns")
```

This is just for x. When I run the program and I test to see if this statement comes up for x, and nothing comes up. What am i doing wrong?

Here is a sample run:

```
0 - check a finished tic-tac-toe
1 - check a finished sudoku
2 - check a game of connect four
3 - quit
choose an option: 0
option 0
For each row, start with x. Enter a combination of x'sand o's up to three characters. For a blank space,enter a period '.'.
top row:xox
middle row:xox
bottom row:xox  
['xox', 'xox', 'xox']
0 - check a finished tic-tac-toe
1 - check a finished sudoku
2 - check a game of connect four
3 - quit
choose an option:
```

This is a bigger portion of the code:

```
for x in i:
            if x not in valid_symbols:
                    print("invalid board - invalid symbol " + x )
                    done = True
                    break
            if ttt.count(x) > 5:
                print("x took too many turns")
```

if I insert an invalid symbol, then it prints that statement.

Comment: Can you show some example input and the code where you're getting it from the user?

Comment: please don't double post questions - [checking a tic tac toe game on python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366969/checking-a-tic-tac-toe-game-on-python)