# checking a tic tac toe game on python

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x

I'm working on this project where I check a finished tic tac toe game. The user inputs a combination of x's and o's and periods (max of 3) in each row (there are 3 rows). I have to check if either x or o took too many turns. This is what I have:

```
if ttt.count(x) > 5:
                    print("x took too many turns")
```

This is just for x. When I run the program and I test to see if this statement comes up for x, and nothing comes up. What am i doing wrong?

Here is a sample run:

```
0 - check a finished tic-tac-toe
1 - check a finished sudoku
2 - check a game of connect four
3 - quit
choose an option: 0
option 0
For each row, start with x. Enter a combination of x'sand o's up to three characters. For a blank space,enter a period '.'.
top row:xox
middle row:xox
bottom row:xox  
['xox', 'xox', 'xox']
0 - check a finished tic-tac-toe
1 - check a finished sudoku
2 - check a game of connect four
3 - quit
choose an option:
```

This is a bigger portion of the code:

```
for x in i:
            if x not in valid_symbols:
                    print("invalid board - invalid symbol " + x )
                    done = True
                    break
            if ttt.count(x) > 5:
                print("x took too many turns")
```

if I insert an invalid symbol, then it prints that statement.

Comment: It may be a bigger portion, but you're missing the most essential portion - where you actually define `ttt` (which happens to be a terrible variable name, btw). Also, if you indent with 4 spaces, instead of tabs, you'll find things are a lot better in Python.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. ttt is the variable name for the tic tac toe which is defined as: 
ttt= list()

Comment: `tic_tac_toe` or `game` or `board` might be better names.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you misunderstand what the contents of `ttt` are. Open up the interpreter and try the following:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> tic_tac_toe = []
>>> tic_tac_toe.append(input('Top row: '))
Top row: xxx
>>>
>>> tic_tac_toe
['xxx']
>>> tic_tac_toe.count('x')
0
>>> tic_tac_toe.count('xxx')
1
```

What happens when you `.append('xox')`? What does the list look like?

Comment: @Wanye Werner I edited my answer to show you what I did to append my rows

Comment: What I have to append my rows is ttt.append(rows) and then I print(ttt). This is in the range of the col_size which is 3.

Comment: What I don't understand is that nothing comes up about the count part of my code

Comment: Did you try it in the interpreter?